# Proof by pumping lemma

Tags: formal-languages, pumping-lemma

I'm trying to use the pumping lemma proof to show that the following language is *context-free* rather than *regular*

> $\{ba^n bc^n | n \geq 1\}$

I've been looking at tutorials on Youtube to try and gain an understanding but as of yet I cannot get my head around it.

Is someone able to take my example and show step by step how to solve using the lemma.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There exists a pumping lemma for regular languages and a pumping lemma for context-free languages. However, it is not easy to prove that a language is regular/context-free using the corresponding lemma, you have to check ALL strings, which is loads of work. The lemmas are mostly used to proof that the language is NOT regular/context-free.

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. Your question may then be reopened.
Good luck!